# Database Inspector in Android Studio not showing strings

Tags: database, android-studio, kotlin, android-room

So i've created a simple database using Kotlin to create a user with some profile data. Thing is, only the integers are shown in the database, not the strings. I tried doing some research, in vain. Please see the image below :
[image: only str are shown]

Here is the code of my main class file :

```
package com.ebookfrenzy.splashscreen10

import androidx.appcompat.app.AppCompatActivity
import android.os.Bundle
import android.widget.Button
import android.widget.EditText

class TestBD : AppCompatActivity() {
    override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_test_bd)

    title="TestBD"
    val id  = findViewById<EditText>(R.id.eT_id)
    //val newId : Int = id.text.toString().toInt()

    val nom = findViewById<EditText>(R.id.eT_nom)
    val newNom : String = nom.text.toString()

    val prenom = findViewById<EditText>(R.id.eT_prenom)
    val newPrenom : String = prenom.text.toString()

    val age = findViewById<EditText>(R.id.eT_age)
    //val newAge : Int = age.text.toString().toInt()

    val taille = findViewById<EditText>(R.id.eT_taille)
    //val newTaille : Int = taille.text.toString().toInt()

    val club = findViewById<EditText>(R.id.eT_club)
    val newClub : String = club.text.toString()

    val date_start = findViewById<EditText>(R.id.eT_start_date)
    val newStartDate : String = date_start.text.toString()

    val poids = findViewById<EditText>(R.id.eT_poids)
    //val newPoids : Int = poids.text.toString().toInt()

    val materiel = findViewById<EditText>(R.id.eT_materiel)
    val newMateriel : String = materiel.text.toString()

    val note = findViewById<EditText>(R.id.eT_notelibre)
    val newNote : String = note.text.toString()

    val d_g = findViewById<EditText>(R.id.eT_dg)
    val newDG : String = d_g.text.toString()

    val c_p = findViewById<EditText>(R.id.eT_cp)
    val newCP : String = c_p.text.toString()

    val id_suppr = findViewById<EditText>(R.id.eT_idsuppr)
    //val newIdSuppr : Int = id_suppr.text.toString().toInt()

    val dbManager = DatabaseManager(this)


    val bouton_add : Button = findViewById(R.id.bt_ajout_user)
    val bouton_suppr : Button = findViewById(R.id.bt_suppr_user)

    bouton_add.setOnClickListener {
        dbManager.creerTireur(id.text.toString().toInt(),newNom,newPrenom,age.text.toString().toInt(),newCP,newDG,newStartDate,newClub,poids.text.toString().toInt(),taille.text.toString().toInt(),newNote,newMateriel)
    }

    bouton_suppr.setOnClickListener {
        dbManager.supprimerTireur(id_suppr.text.toString().toInt())
    }



}
}
```

Here is the code of my DatabaseManager :

```
package com.ebookfrenzy.splashscreen10

import android.content.Context
import androidx.room.Room

class DatabaseManager(context: Context) {
    private val db = Room.databaseBuilder(
        context.applicationContext,
        AimGeniusDatabase::class.java, "aim_genius_database"
    ).allowMainThreadQueries().build()

private val tireurDao : tireurDao = db.TireurDao()
private val entraineurDao : entraineurDao = db.EntraineurDao()

fun insertTireur(user : DataTireur){
    tireurDao.insertTireur(user)
}

fun creerTireur(
    id: Int,
    nom: String,
    prenom: String,
    age: Int,
    c_p: String,
    d_g: String,
    start_date: String,
    club: String,
    poids: Int,
    taille: Int,
    notelibre: String,
    materiel: String){

    val user = DataTireur(id, nom, prenom, age,c_p,d_g,start_date,club,poids,taille,notelibre,materiel)
    tireurDao.insertTireur(user)
}

fun supprimerTireur(userId : Int){
    val tireur = tireurDao.getTireur(userId)
    tireur?.let {
        tireurDao.deleteTireur(it)
    }
}

}
```

Here is the code of my entities class file :

```
package com.ebookfrenzy.splashscreen10

import androidx.room.Entity
import androidx.room.PrimaryKey
import java.util.Date


@Entity(tableName = "Entraineurs")
data class DataEntraineurs(
    @PrimaryKey(autoGenerate = true) val id : Long = 0,
    var ent_nom : String,
    var ent_nb_session : Int,
    var ent_prenom : String
)

@Entity(tableName = "Tireurs")
data class DataTireur(
    @PrimaryKey(autoGenerate = true) val id : Int = 0,
    var tir_nom : String,
    var tir_prenom : String,
    var tir_age : Int,
    var tir_c_p : String,
    var tir_g_d : String,
    var tir_start_date : String,
    var tir_club : String,
    var tir_poids : Int,
    var tir_taille_cm : Int,
    var tir_note_libre : String,
    var tir_materiel : String
)
```

And finally here is the code of DAO File :

```
package com.ebookfrenzy.splashscreen10

import androidx.room.Dao
import androidx.room.Delete
import androidx.room.Insert
import androidx.room.OnConflictStrategy
import androidx.room.Query
import androidx.room.Update
import com.ebookfrenzy.splashscreen10.model.Entraineurs


@Dao
interface entraineurDao {

//Methodes pour l'entraineur
@Insert(onConflict = OnConflictStrategy.REPLACE)
fun insertEntraineur(user: DataEntraineurs): Long

@Update
fun updateEntraineur(user: DataEntraineurs)

@Query("SELECT * FROM entraineurs WHERE id =:userId")
fun getEntraineur(userId: Int): DataEntraineurs?

@Delete
fun deleteEntraineur(user: DataEntraineurs)
}

@Dao
interface tireurDao {

//methodes pour le tireur
@Query("SELECT * FROM Tireurs WHERE id =:userId")
fun getTireur(userId: Int): DataTireur?

@Insert(onConflict = OnConflictStrategy.REPLACE)
fun insertTireur(user: DataTireur): Long

@Update
fun updateTireur(user: DataTireur)

@Delete
fun deleteTireur(user : DataTireur)
}
```

Thank you for any help ! I appreciate it

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Obviously the issue is **not a problem inserting a row** into the database as this has been done. i.e. **`App Inspection` is showing what is**.

Therefore the issue is likely that you are **inserting empty strings**.
If you place a breakpoint on the line `dbManager.creerTireur(id.text.toString().toInt(),newNom,newPrenom,age.text.toString().toInt(),newCP,newDG,newStartDate,newClub,poids.text.toString().toInt(),taille.text.toString().toInt(),newNote,newMateriel)`

and then run in debug mode (the little green bug icon) then you will see something like *(see note below re layout)*:-

[image]

What is happening is that you are collecting the values before any values have been input i.e. as soon as the layout has been set.

**Fix**

If instead you use:-

```
    bouton_add.setOnClickListener {
        dbManager.creerTireur(
            id.text.toString().toInt(),
            nom.text.toString(),
            prenom.text.toString(),
            age.text.toString().toInt(),
            c_p.text.toString(),
            d_g.text.toString(),
            date_start.text.toString(),
            club.text.toString(),
            poids.text.toString().toInt(),
            taille.text.toString().toInt(),
            note.text.toString(),
            materiel.text.toString()
        )
    }
```

i.e. you are **THEN** retrieving the values WHEN/IMMEDIATELY AFTER THE BUTTON IS CLICKED, for example *(see note re layout below)*:-

[image]

As such you might as well have the main class file as:-

```
override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main)

    title="TestBD"
    val id  = findViewById<EditText>(R.id.eT_id)
    val nom = findViewById<EditText>(R.id.eT_nom)
    val prenom = findViewById<EditText>(R.id.eT_prenom)
    val age = findViewById<EditText>(R.id.eT_age)
    val taille = findViewById<EditText>(R.id.eT_taille)
    val club = findViewById<EditText>(R.id.eT_club)
    val date_start = findViewById<EditText>(R.id.eT_start_date)
    val poids = findViewById<EditText>(R.id.eT_poids)
    val materiel = findViewById<EditText>(R.id.eT_materiel)
    val note = findViewById<EditText>(R.id.eT_notelibre)
    val d_g = findViewById<EditText>(R.id.eT_dg)
    val c_p = findViewById<EditText>(R.id.eT_cp)
    val id_suppr = findViewById<EditText>(R.id.eT_idsuppr)
    val dbManager = DatabaseManager(this)
    val bouton_add : Button = findViewById(R.id.bt_ajout_user)
    val bouton_suppr : Button = findViewById(R.id.bt_suppr_user)

    bouton_add.setOnClickListener {
        dbManager.creerTireur(
            id.text.toString().toInt(),
            nom.text.toString(),
            prenom.text.toString(),
            age.text.toString().toInt(),
            c_p.text.toString(),
            d_g.text.toString(),
            date_start.text.toString(),
            club.text.toString(),
            poids.text.toString().toInt(),
            taille.text.toString().toInt(),
            note.text.toString(),
            materiel.text.toString()
        )
    }

    bouton_suppr.setOnClickListener {
        dbManager.supprimerTireur(id_suppr.text.toString().toInt())
    }
}
```

- i.e. the the new???? fields serve no purpose.
- **NOTE** the layout used above was improvised and thus does not match the your layout but effectively mimics the functionality enough to provide the answer.

Comment: Thank you so much, it works now. I understood very clearly thanks to your answer!